# What are the safe materials for an aquatic turtle aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, reptiles, turtles, substrate, decorations

What are safe materials for inside an aquatic turtle aquarium? I've seen plans using PVC, concrete, lumber, etc. but am concerned about chemicals.

Comment: If you are [worried about chemicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_free), you should avoid contaminating the aquarium with dihydrogen monoxide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending some hours researching, I couldn't find any list of turtle safe materials.

The only material I could think about was wood: if it´s too soft, perhaps you turtle could begin to bite it and remove small chips, and could cause some problems. If the wood is chemically treated, the problems with chemicals could be more intense. And if it´s not treated, the humidity could cause fungus, and it would be even worst.

For other materials: I think that everything that is safe for human use would be safe for turtles too, just remember that they will be wet (and so some materials could decompose, melt, get weird, I don´t know).